# Load Next Posts With AJAX not working with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, jquery, ajax

I am using this [plugin](http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/) to load in my next posts with AJAX. I have implemented it into my site and it is showing the load more posts button however once you click on the 'load more posts' button it then says there is nothing to load.

Below is my code:

```
    // Add code to index pages.
if( !is_singular() ) {  
    // Queue JS and CSS
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'pbd-alp-load-posts',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/load-posts.js',
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0',
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'pbd-alp-style',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/style.css',
        false,
        '1.0',
        'all'
    );



    // What page are we on? And what is the pages limit?
    $max = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    // Add some parameters for the JS.
    wp_localize_script(
        'pbd-alp-load-posts',
        'pbd_alp',
        array(
            'startPage' => $paged,
            'maxPages' => $max,
            'nextLink' => next_posts($max, false)
        )
    );
}
```

I am trying to do this on a custom post and I think the problem may be where it says is_singular. I tried updating this to the following:

```
if( !is_post_type_archive($work) )
```

But when i change it to this it not longer detects the plugin and goes back to the standard pagination.

Here is the jQuery as well:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// The number of the next page to load (/page/x/).
var pageNum = parseInt(pbd_alp.startPage) + 1;

// The maximum number of pages the current query can return.
var max = parseInt(pbd_alp.maxPages);

// The link of the next page of posts.
var nextLink = pbd_alp.nextLink;

/**
 * Replace the traditional navigation with our own,
 * but only if there is at least one page of new posts to load.
 */
if(pageNum <= max) {
    // Insert the "More Posts" link.
    $('#postContent')
        .append('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')
        .append('<p id="pbd-alp-load-posts"><a href="#">Load More Posts</a></p>');

    // Remove the traditional navigation.
    $('.navigation').remove();
}


/**
 * Load new posts when the link is clicked.
 */
$('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').click(function() {

    // Are there more posts to load?
    if(pageNum <= max) {

        // Show that we're working.
        $(this).text('Loading posts...');

        $('.pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum).load(nextLink + ' .post',
            function() {
                // Update page number and nextLink.
                pageNum++;
                nextLink = nextLink.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]?/, '/page/'+ pageNum);

                // Add a new placeholder, for when user clicks again.
                $('#pbd-alp-load-posts')
                    .before('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')

                // Update the button message.
                if(pageNum <= max) {
                    $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('Load More Posts');
                } else {
                    $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('No more posts to load.');
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').append('.');
    }   

    return false;
});
});
```

---

Update:

This is what I get after a var dump:

```
array(61) { ["post_type"]=> string(4) "work" ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=> string(0) "" ["p"]=> int(0) ["post_parent"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["static"]=> string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(0) "" ["page_id"]=> int(0) ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0) ["year"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0) "" ["author"]=> string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=> string(0) "" ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["paged"]=> int(0) ["comments_popup"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_key"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_value"]=> string(0) "" ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=> string(0) "" ["sentence"]=> string(0) "" ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_order"]=> string(0) "" ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["suppress_filters"]=> bool(false) ["cache_results"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_term_cache"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_meta_cache"]=> bool(true) ["posts_per_page"]=> int(2) ["nopaging"]=> bool(false) ["comments_per_page"]=> string(2) "50" ["no_found_rows"]=> bool(false) ["order"]=> string(4) "DESC" }
```

Var dump immediately after wp_query

```
array(61) { ["post_type"]=> string(4) "work" ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=> string(0) "" ["p"]=> int(0) ["post_parent"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["static"]=> string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(0) "" ["page_id"]=> int(0) ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0) ["year"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0) "" ["author"]=> string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=> string(0) "" ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["paged"]=> int(0) ["comments_popup"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_key"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_value"]=> string(0) "" ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=> string(0) "" ["sentence"]=> string(0) "" ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_order"]=> string(0) "" ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["suppress_filters"]=> bool(false) ["cache_results"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_term_cache"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_meta_cache"]=> bool(true) ["posts_per_page"]=> int(2) ["nopaging"]=> bool(false) ["comments_per_page"]=> string(2) "50" ["no_found_rows"]=> bool(false) ["order"]=> string(4) "DESC" }
```

Comment: The pbd-ajax-load-posts.php uses the global $wp_query...have you tried dumping it to see what the "post_type" value is?  

`var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);`


You may need to set the post_type to your CPT...just a thought.

Comment: Ive done a var_dump and posted that in my question above.

Comment: Two questions:  1.  Is "work" the name of your CPT?  2.  Did you do the dump immediately after the global $wp_query declaration (around line 15 or so)?

Comment: Yes 'work' is the name of my CPT. I didnt do it immediately after I put it into my template. However I have done it immediately after wp_query now and added that to my answer.

Comment: Hmmm...have you tried this on a non-CPT filled page, i.e. can you get it to work at all on your site?

Comment: yes it works fine on a main blog page, something is conflicting it on a CPT page which is very annoying :(

Comment: Is there anything on your template page that manipulates the query?  ... sorry to leave you hanging but I'll be off the net for the next 7 hours or so...will check back in later.

Comment: Did you get this fixed?